# How do I fetch Firebase data dynamically in HTML template?

Tags: angular, typescript, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, ionic2

I have a Firebase realtime database which has two data objects. `Tweets` & `Users`. A `tweet` object has a property `userid`. I would like to fetch the name of the user for that tweet.

I'm doing something like this:

```
<ion-item *ngFor="let tweet of tweets| async" >
{{(af.database.object('/Users/'+tweet.userid+'/name') | async)}}
</ion-item>
```

It does get the JSON, but I'm not sure how get just the value.
When I try to debug using |json pipe:

```
<ion-item *ngFor="let tweet of tweets| async" >
{{(af.database.object('/Users/'+tweet.userid+'/name') | async | json)}} 
</ion-item>
```

I do see the value

```
{
  "$value": "username",
  "$key": "name"
}
```

printed out.
What I want is just the output `username`.

How do I get just that value?

Answer (score 2):

Try :

```
<ion-item *ngFor="let tweet of tweets| async" >
{{(af.database.object('/Users/'+tweet.userid+'/name') | async)?.$value}} 
</ion-item>
```